# Pytorch Error: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu

Tags: python, pytorch, resnet

I am trying to implement a ResNet with Pytorch, and this error occurs when I'm trying to check the model summary. **I've gone through relevant questions on Stackoverflow and tried their answers, but none of them solved my problem.**

Below is my model class:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ResNet, self).__init__()
        self.layer_1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 3, out_channels = 64, kernel_size = 7, stride=2, padding=3),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.layer_2 = nn.Sequential(
            self.resblock(64, 64),
            self.resblock(64, 64)
        )
        self.layer_3 = nn.Sequential(
            self.resblock(64, 128),
            self.resblock(128, 128)
        )
        self.layer_4 = nn.Sequential(
            self.resblock(128, 256),
            self.resblock(256, 256)
        )
        self.layer_5 = nn.Sequential(
            self.resblock(256, 512),
            self.resblock(512, 512)
        )
                
    class resblock(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, input_c, output_c):
            super().__init__()
            if input_c == output_c:
                self.step1 = nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Conv2d(in_channels = output_c, out_channels = output_c, kernel_size = 3, stride=1, padding=1),
                    nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features = output_c, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1)
                )
                self.shortcut = nn.Identity()
            else:
                self.step1 = nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Conv2d(in_channels = input_c, out_channels = output_c, kernel_size = 3, stride=2, padding=1),
                    nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features = output_c, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1)
                )
                self.shortcut = nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Conv2d(in_channels = input_c, out_channels = output_c, kernel_size=1, stride=2),
                    nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features = output_c, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1)
                )
            self.step2 = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(in_channels = output_c, out_channels = output_c, kernel_size = 3, stride=1, padding=1),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features = output_c, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1)
            )
            
        def forward(self, x):
            x_shortcut = self.shortcut(x)
            
            x = self.step1(x)
            x = nn.ReLU()(x)
            x = self.step2(x)
            x = nn.ReLU()(x)
            y = nn.ReLU()(x_shortcut + x)
            return y

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer_1(x)
        x = self.layer_2(x)
        x = self.layer_3(x)
        x = self.layer_4(x)
        x = self.layer_5(x)
        x = nn.AvgPool2d(x.size()[-1], stride=None, padding=0)(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = nn.Linear(512, 10)(x)
        return x
```

And below the test code which returns error:

```
from torchsummary import summary
resnet18 = ResNet()
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
resnet18.to(device)
summary(resnet18, (3, 224, 224))

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument mat1 in method wrapper_addmm)
```

I'm confused because I've run all example codes from [model.summary()'s GitHub page](https://github.com/sksq96/pytorch-summary) and they all went on well. I am a total rookie in PyTorch so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Change the last layer in `forward` of `Resnet` to `x = nn.Linear(512, 10).to('cuda')(x)`. Or initialize another layer like `self.fc = nn.Linear(512, 10)` and change in `forward` to `x = self.fc(x)` to be included when the model is set `to('cuda')`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I guess we have to make the last layer predefined inside the model, otherwise it won't automatically fall into the same device as the model?